# One of the MediatR Validator is not getting registered in net6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mediatr

I have two Validators for MediatR

```
public class GamerDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<GamerDto>
{
    public GamerDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Username).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(50)
            .WithMessage("Usernmae Name is required");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CreateGamerCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateGamerCommand>
{
    private readonly IGamerRepository _gamerRepository;

    public CreateGamerCommandValidator(IGamerRepository gamerRepository)
    {
        _gamerRepository = gamerRepository;
        
        RuleFor(v => v.Username).Must((gamer, cancellation) =>
        {
            var gamerExists =  _gamerRepository.AnyAsync(y => y.Username == gamer.Username).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return !gamerExists;
        }).WithMessage("User already exist - {PropertyValue}");
    }
}
```

I have registered these like mentioned below

```
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program));

        services.Scan(s => s
                        .FromAssembliesOf(this.AssemblyMarkerTypes)
                        .AddClasses(false)
                        .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Append)
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithTransientLifetime());
```

ValidatorBehavior Middleware is defined like below

```
public class ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILogger<ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators;

    public ValidatorBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators, ILogger<ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        this.validators = validators;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

The validator "CreateGamerCommandValidator" only gets registered and applied

[image]

The validator "GamerDtoValidator" is ignored. Why? How to fix this so that both the validators will be registered and applied?

**Update#1:**
I was able to fix this by

```
public class GamerDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<GamerDto>
{
    public GamerDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Username).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Usernmae Name is required");

        RuleFor(v => v.Username).MaximumLength(50)
            .WithMessage("Username exceeds the permitted Limit");
    }
}
```

and

```
    public CreateGamerCommandValidator(IMapper mapper, IGamerRepository gamerRepository)
    {
        _gamerRepository = gamerRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;

        this.RuleFor(x => _mapper.Map<GamerDto>(x))
            .SetValidator(new GamerDtoValidator());

        RuleFor(v => v.Username).Must((gamer, cancellation) =>
        {
            var gamerExists =  _gamerRepository.AnyAsync(y => y.Username == gamer.Username).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return !gamerExists;
        }).WithMessage("User already exist - {PropertyValue}");
    }
```

However feels like this is not the way to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The provided screenshot does not prove *"The validator "CreateGamerCommandValidator" only gets registered"* statement. You are resolving `IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators` where `TRequest` seems to be `CreateGamerCommand` so out of two provided validators only one implements `IValidator<CreateGamerCommand>` (transitively from `AbstractValidator<CreateGamerCommand>`).

`GamerDtoValidator` is `AbstractValidator<GamerDto>` so it can't be registered as `IValidator<CreateGamerCommand>` and automatically is registered as `IValidator<GamerDto>`.

Also both should be registered as base `IValidator` interface, so you can check that by resolving `IEnumerable<IValidator>` in your `ValidatorBehavior` but those will not be very useful.

As for how to apply `GamerDto` validator - it hugely depends on what you are trying to achieve and how you application is structured. For example if for some reason `CreateGamerCommand` inherits from `GamerDto` you can resolve `GamerDtoValidator` there and use it. Or you can introduce an interface `IHaveGamerName` (with `Username` property) and implement it in both `CreateGamerCommand` and `GamerDto` and create a validator for `IHaveGamerName` and resolve it where appropriate.